# Comparación de array con texto: uno sí funciona, el otro no

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una práctica donde hago una función y te pide como parámetro un array (práctica de la clave secreta). Ya logré acomodar el array (invertir) y filtrar los `*`; el problema es que al momento de validarlo con el texto, uno sí funciona y el otro no y no tengo idea del porqué.

---------- Código ----------

```
function laClaveSecreta(clave){
    let ordenado = clave.reverse(); //cambia inversamente el array
        ordenado = ordenado.filter((i) => i !== "*"); // filtramos los *
            if (ordenado = "Clave descifrada"){
                return "Clave descifrada";
            }else if (ordenado = "El día es lunes"){
                return "El día es lunes";
           }
    }

// Ejecutando la función con el siguiente parámetro:

    laClaveSecreta( [ "s", "*", "e", "n", "u", "l", " ", "s", "*", "e", " ", "a", "í", "*", "d", " ", "l", "*", "E", "*"] );  

// El resultado que nos devuelve la función es el siguiente: 
"El día es lunes";  

// Ejecutando la función con el siguiente parámetro:

    laClaveSecreta( ["a", "*", "d", "a", "r", "f", "*", "i", "c", "*", "s", "e", "d", " ", "e", "*", "v", "a", "l", "C"] );


// El resultado que nos devuelve la función es el siguiente: 
"Clave descifrada";
```

Comment: Como dice ivanph, no tienes que usar ni el `if` ni el `else if`, después del `filter` puedes hacer simplemente `return ordenado.join('');` y te devolverá la cadena de texto descifrada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los coomparativos se hacen en js coon == o ===.

Cambia esto:
`ordenado = "Clave descifrada"` y `ordenado = "El día es lunes"`

Por `ordenado === "Texto"`.

Por otro lado ordenado es un array y estás comparandolo con un texto, antes de realizar la comparación puedes convertir el array a una cadena de texto de forma fácil con:

```
ordenado.join('');
```

Pero en tu caso no deberías ni usar el if y else, el join retornaría la cadena que buscas para cualquier array.

Answer (score 1):

Funciono!!!..

Les dejo el código.

--------- Código -------

```
function laClaveSecreta(clave){
    let ordenado = clave.reverse(); //cambia inversamente el array
     ordenado = ordenado.filter((i) => i !== "*"); // filtramos los *
      
       if (ordenado.join('') === "Clave descifrada" ){
        console.log("Clave descifrada");
        }else if (ordenado.join('') === "El día es lunes"){
            console.log( "El día es lunes");
            }
}
laClaveSecreta( [ "s", "*", "e", "n", "u", "l", " ", "s", "*", "e", " ", "a", "í", "*", "d", " ", "l", "*", "E", "*"] );  

laClaveSecreta( ["a", "*", "d", "a", "r", "f", "*", "i", "c", "*", "s", "e", "d", " ", "e", "*", "v", "a", "l", "C"] );
```

Opte dejarlo con la opción de 'clave descifrada', puede que alguien quiera esto, podría cambiar este texto y ponerlo como variable del usuario y la parte de ordenado como decodificador, al final se comparan ambas y dará un resultado.

ivanph, gracias maestro, aprendí mucho de usted!!!. :D